# how to capture the longitude and latitude of my location in a UWP project?

Tags: c#, google-maps, uwp, location

I wanted to know how I do to capture my real location in longitude and latitude, I am creating a UWP project with C #

Thanks!

Comment: Check the GeoCoordinateWatcher Class https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.device.location.geocoordinatewatcher?view=netframework-4.7.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to use [GeoLocator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.geolocation.geolocator) class and for that make sure to enable **Location capability** in your app manifest and then the location with following code.

```
var geoLocator = new Geolocator();  
geoLocator.DesiredAccuracy = PositionAccuracy.High;  
var pos = await geoLocator.GetGeopositionAsync();  
string latitude = "Latitude: " + pos.Coordinate.Point.Position.Latitude.ToString();  
string longitude = "Longitude: " + pos.Coordinate.Point.Position.Longitude.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

For getting your current location within uwp, you need add `<DeviceCapability Name="location"/>` in project `package.appxmanifest` file first. UWP has provided location APIs in the [`Windows.Devices.Geolocation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Devices.Geolocation) namespace.
And this is [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/maps-and-location/get-location) that describe detail code process.

This is official [code sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/MapControl) that contain most scenario about using MapControl.